# Expanding 2D array with realloc gives me a memory leak

Tags: c++, c, memory

```
board = (char**)realloc(board, numbers[0] * sizeof (char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers[0]; i++) {
        board[i] = (char*)malloc(numbers[1] * sizeof (char));
    }
```

board is [y][x] but i want to expand it so it is [numbers[0]][numbers[1]], but this code gives me a memory leak (it's coming from this i checked it).
Why and how to do it properly?

Later on it's free like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++){
              free(board[i]);
        }
        free(board);
```

It's created like this:

```
char** board = (char**)malloc(boardY * sizeof * board); 
for (int i = 0; i < boardSizeY; i++) { 
board[i] = (char*)malloc(boardX * sizeof * *board); 
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand, how to do it properly then?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some commentary on the existing code:

```
// assume at this point that board[0] is pointing to a malloc()'d
// buffer, as is board[1], board[2], and so on

// below here you call realloc(), which resizes the
// pointer-array either larger or smaller.  If it makes
// it smaller, then you've lost access to the pointers
// that were at the end of the old array, so the
// buffers they pointed to have been leaked.

board = (char**)realloc(board, numbers[0] * sizeof (char*));
for (int i = 0; i < numbers[0]; i++) {
    // In any case, here you are overwriting all the pointers
    // in (board), so any buffers they previously pointed to
    // are now leaked (because no longer have access to them,
    // so you can never call free() on them after this)
    board[i] = (char*)malloc(numbers[1] * sizeof (char));
}
```

... so, what to do instead?  How about something like this:

```
// before updating numbers[0] or numbers[1], we'll
// free any old allocations we had
for (int i = 0; i < numbers[0]; i++) {
   free(board[i]);
}

// update numbers[0] and numbers[1] to their new values...
numbers[0] = [...]
numbers[1] = [...];

// now we can resize board and allocate new sub-buffers
board = (char**)realloc(board, numbers[0] * sizeof (char*));
for (int i = 0; i < numbers[0]; i++) {
   board[i] = (char*)malloc(numbers[1] * sizeof (char));
}
```

Of course, storing a 2D array as an array-of-pointers-to-arrays is kind of overly-complicated and inefficient anyway, when you could just store all your data inside a single allocation:

```
size_t arraySize = numbers[0] * numbers[1];
char * board = (char *) malloc(numbers[0] * numbers[1]);
...
free(board);

char getValueAt(const char * board, int sizeX, int x, int y)
{
   return board[(x*sizeX)+y];
}

void setValueAt(char * board, int sizeX, int x, int y, char newValue)
{
   board[(x*sizeX)+y] = newValue;
}
```

Comment: i added this for loop before realloc and i'm still getting memory leak

Comment: If you include a minimal, compilable example in your question, I can compile and run it on my computer and investigate any memory-leaks that occur.  Without that, I can't do much more than guess, so here is my guess:  your program contains a bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
board = (char**)realloc(board, numbers[0] * sizeof (char*));
```

This is not good because each pointers in `board` are lost, and it causes memory leaks as you say.

I think that there are two approaches.

1. `free()` all pointers in `board` before `realloc`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++){
   free(board[i]);
}
board = (char**)realloc(board, numbers[0] * sizeof (char*));
for (int i = 0; i < numbers[0]; i++) {
    board[i] = (char*)malloc(numbers[1] * sizeof (char));
}
```

2. Save all pointers to another array before `realloc()` and restore them after `realloc()`

```
char **temp = (char **)malloc(numbers[0] * sizeof(char *));
for (int i = 0; i < numbers[0]; i++) {
  temp[i] = board[i];
}
board = (char**)realloc(board, numbers[0] * sizeof (char*));
for (int i = 0; i < numbers[0]; i++) {
  board[i] = temp[i];
}
free(temp);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was wrong.